# How to get relative parent source files for use in tests subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have a directory structure like..

```
/
    source_1.cpp
    source_2.cpp
    source_1.hpp
    source_2.hpp
    CMakeLists.txt
    /tests
        test_1.cpp
        test_2.cpp
        CMakeLists.txt
```

I'm writing the tests in the tests directory but the tests need to be build with the parent source as well. I don't want to make my root build a library.

I can get access to the parent files by using

```
get_target_properties( <parent-target> PARENT_SOURCE SOURCES )
```

but the list returned is simply a list of the file names and doesn't have the PATH, i.e. source_1.cpp;source_2.cpp;..  etc.

Does anyone know how to get a list of relative paths to the parent targets source files ?

Comment: `I don't want to make my root build a library.` why? `and doesn't have the PATH` There is `SOURCE_DIR` property

Comment: Because it's not a library, it's an application built up from a collection of source files. I want to be able to test each source file in the tests subdirectory and need access to the relative (or absolute) path of the parent source files

Comment: So make a library. Make an application that has main and links with that library. Test the library.

Comment: How do you create the SOURCES list. I am guessing you just list the names of the files? Try prefixing them, e.g., `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source_1.cpp`.

Comment: If you want to compile the sources with different compiler options, there's still the option of listing the sources as public sources (`target_sources(... PUBLIC ...)`) of an interface library. This should add them to the sources of any target liking the interface lib and also allows you to bundle additional properties shared between the main executable and the test executable...